# Function header clarification

Tags: c, arrays, function

So I have this function where we calculate the distance between two points in a 2D array.

`double distance( int p1[], int p2[] );` is the header of our distance formula. My question about this is: What exactly am I sending into the function? I think that I'm sending in an array to the function, so the function call would look something like: `distance(array[numRows][numCols], array[centerRow][centerCol])`

I think that it is wrong on my part, but that is why I'm asking about this...I'm unsure on what I'm calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double distance( int p1[], int p2[] );
```

is equivalent to

```
double distance( int *p1, int *p2 );
```

It means that your function is expecting a pointer to `int`. You need to pass address of the (first) element of your arrays as argument to this function.

Comment: Ok, I had a small feeling that was what it was supposed to be. So since I'm using an int** as my array I would just use a single row of it?

Comment: If you wanna use a single row of your 2D array then change your function parameters to `int (*)p1[col], int(*)p2[col]`.

Comment: I can't change the parameter. I'm just trying to find the distance between two points, would I want to send in `array[i][j] and array[centerRow][centerCol]?`

Comment: No. If you don't wanna change parameters then you need to pass a pointer to `int`. Either you can pass `array[i]` or `&array[i][j]`.